# How to pass Char array back

Tags: arrays, c, function, return, typedef

I'm writing a code to decode a specific, all function seem to be working fine with correct decoding result but I'm struggling to get the data into tydef struct

I'm define var like this

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char utctime[8];
    unsigned char Lat[11];
    unsigned char LatDirect;
    unsigned char Status;
    unsigned char Long[11];
    unsigned char LongDirect;
    //unsigned float speed;
    unsigned char date[6];
}StrGPSDATA;
```

```
unsigned char datatestRealword1[100] = " *** TEST DATA HERE *** ";
```

Here is pseudo code.

```
unsigned char parseByDelimiter(char *inputData, const char delims, int index, unsigned int maxIndexSize){
    unsigned char valOut[maxDataOut] = {0};
    // Parse/Split value //

    return valOut;  // Debugging show correct result

}
```

```
void RMCDecode(unsigned char *dataIn, unsigned int sizeIn){
    unsigned char dataExt[60] = {0};
    // do something to get value to //

    
    parseByDelimiter(dataExt, ',', 1, 60);  // Send decoded value to parse
    
}
```

```
void main(void){
    RMCDecode(datatestRealword1, 100);

}
```

A debugger report a correct value

But after when I tried

```
GPSDATARMC.utctime = parseByDelimiter(RMC_DATA, ',', 0, 10);
```

I gave an error incompatible data type, I don't know how to write value into my typedef. Anyone got an idea?

Thank you

Comment: `return valOut;` for a function returning `unsigned char` isn't valid C. The root of your problems is that you don't have warnings enabled or don't pay attention to them. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: Since `valOut` is a local array declared inside the function  `parseByDelimiter`, it will only exist for as long as the function `parseDelimiter` is running. Therefore, there is no point in that function returning a pointer to that array, because the array will cease to exist as soon as the function returns. A pointer to a non-existant array is useless.